# How to use Stripe with Chrome Extension MV3 with React & Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, stripe-payments

I'm developing a Chrome extension in MV3. I need to integrate Stripe with this extension. This extension overrides the new tab. And I'm using ReactJs and Webpack.

NPM Package using: React Stripe.js

Right now I'm getting

```
stripe.esm.js:30 Refused to load the script 'https://js.stripe.com/v3' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I've tried adding

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' https://js.stripe.com/v3; object-src 'self'; frame-src https://js.stripe.com/v3"
  }
```

in manifest.json but I get this.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to use it like this in MV3?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: ManifestV3 disallows external code by design. Download the script and load it like any other extension script.

Comment: ..which one absolutely should not do, because, quoting: "Note: To be PCI compliant, you must load Stripe.js directly from https://js.stripe.com. You cannot include it in a bundle or host it yourself."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the simple and straight forward answer is that you cannot do your implementation this way. First “[Remotely hosted code](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview#remotely-hosted-code) is no longer allowed; an extension can only execute JavaScript that is included within its package.” as per the chrome developer documentation [0].

Stripe has also addressed this issue in their GitHub which you can read more about here [1].

As for the best way to handle this situation is for your extension to generate a link to an external website that you would create. In there, you’d be able to create a CheckoutSession or even integrate with PaymentElements.

I hope this shed some light on how to move forward.

[0] https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#feature-summary

[1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/issues/273